# How to get the centroid of one cluster?

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have obtained several clusters of pedestrian trajectories by **hierarchical clustering**. Now for each cluster, I wish to merge all the pedestrian trajectories into one "centroid trajectory".

I am currently implementing the hierarchical clustering with the [Python scipy.cluster.hierarchy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html).

Is there any off-the-shelf function to get the centroid of one cluster? If there isn't, general suggestions on merging methods are also greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of challenges with centroids on trajectories, in particular the temporal aspects. Most likely, your trajectories will *not* align perfectly in time; and due to temporal sampling also not too well in space unless allowing interpolation.

How about using the medoid instead of the centroid? I.e. as representative object, choose the one which has the smallest average distance to all cluster members. Judging from your earlier posts, you already have the full distance matrix anyway, so you can just look up these numbers and find the minimum within-cluster sum.

Comment: This sounds like a nice suggestion, will try it later:)